# Extra number after the image name on heroku why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

The image work locally but cant work in heroku

Theres extra number after the image name

I put this line in application.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true

but still not working I spend two days just trying to figure out please any one help me

This is my heroku logs -t

```
    Your version of git is 1.9.3. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
2015-07-31T17:48:33.127184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/page1-img2-7788f1952874c5b24b7fdffe50e165a4.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=359fce6b-071b-4f96-8130-a967d2733bab fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-07-31T17:48:33.117125+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/slider-3-91ee388062b58dc3b0a007f28c447ce2.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=387f342e-2032-4a17-be97-29ebfae48ac7 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-07-31T17:48:33.304821+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/next.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=1d340ce3-d176-4a7b-af82-9d91e5972ff1 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=88ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-07-31T17:48:33.219883+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/icon-3.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=a1ea1755-5547-4033-8e3e-100c4b3aa599 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:48:33.322375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/page1-img4-8834d46cb8455d0dc8406ec3242c4d08.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=c796f8db-32ea-4c1c-ad0f-91ecc953ae77 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=67ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-07-31T17:48:33.323176+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/icon-1.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=aef70137-20db-41eb-84b3-4652fa1c4712 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=76ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:48:33.215837+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/icon-3.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:48:33 +0000
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285915+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285920+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/next.png"):
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285922+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285926+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285927+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285929+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285948+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285950+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285951+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285953+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285954+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285955+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285957+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285958+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285961+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285962+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285965+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285968+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285969+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285970+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:48:33.219359+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/images/next.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:48:33 +0000
2015-07-31T17:48:33.330924+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/nav-bg.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:48:33 +0000
2015-07-31T17:48:33.285971+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:48:33.298463+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/images/prev.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:48:33 +0000
2015-07-31T17:48:33.421556+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/bc.jpg" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:48:33 +0000
2015-07-31T17:48:33.291505+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/icon-2.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:48:33 +0000
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303808+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303812+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/prev.png"):
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303816+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303814+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303818+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303822+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303821+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303826+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303829+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303828+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303831+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303834+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303832+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303838+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303836+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303842+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303839+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303840+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303843+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303844+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303846+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303848+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303849+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:48:33.303850+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:48:33.310140+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/icon-1.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:48:33 +0000
2015-07-31T17:48:33.403870+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/marker.gif" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:48:33 +0000
2015-07-31T17:48:33.340051+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/nav-bg.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=8f0351fc-bbb7-4a90-aee6-8f9e3984c380 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=24ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:48:33.309951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/prev.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=436c9568-e9fa-4864-93aa-6b88fe3c5a0b fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=86ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-07-31T17:48:33.431781+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/bc.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=d9e256fc-0519-4b79-8ee7-92ca0491e71a fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:48:33.321484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/icon-2.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=61a8560b-cae1-4b5e-9fd4-d9c269034dae fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=92ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:48:33.411810+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/marker.gif" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=d63c575d-8682-4b35-ac75-d70df0bbef95 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:48:44.863882+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a547579 by logicrey@gmail.com
2015-07-31T17:48:44.863882+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v50 created by logicrey@gmail.com
2015-07-31T17:48:44.912730+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-07-31T17:48:44.912738+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-07-31T17:48:45.004974+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-07-31T17:48:47.197220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-07-31T17:48:47.627134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 19825 -e production`
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672445+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-31 17:48:47] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672453+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672455+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672457+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672458+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672459+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672461+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672466+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672464+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672467+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672470+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672469+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672666+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-31 17:48:47] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672745+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672471+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672568+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-31 17:48:47] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-07-31T17:48:47.672473+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-07-31T17:48:48.731841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-07-31T17:48:50.995358+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-07-31T17:48:50.956374+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-31 17:48:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-07-31T17:48:50.956401+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-31 17:48:50] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-07-31T17:48:50.956699+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-07-31 17:48:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=19825
2015-07-31T17:49:20.329431+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-07-31T17:49:20.329437+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:19825
2015-07-31T17:49:20.329439+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-07-31T17:49:20.329442+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2015-07-31T17:49:20.329444+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-07-31T17:49:20.329445+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:49:20 +0000
2015-07-31T17:49:20.386420+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2015-07-31T17:49:20.401949+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 6.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2015-07-31T17:49:20.415573+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=364f1db4-d303-438d-85cd-e7b5cf4a21b1 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=82ms status=200 bytes=9411
2015-07-31T17:49:20.588832+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-d569ca2ebf16ea18705c2fd79a329a0a.css" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=7f762f03-38cf-4aea-92bd-1081aa923c13 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=71ms status=200 bytes=515455
2015-07-31T17:49:20.400137+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.4ms)
2015-07-31T17:49:20.570149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/bs-2222d03154e495e8d391718bc3cdc0e6.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=54a4b32a-fa2c-413d-afa1-85d7184b0def fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=53ms status=200 bytes=22223
2015-07-31T17:49:20.606632+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-739b24b91a184149207cca71402d0feb.js" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=f59d672c-9b68-44e5-9f8c-9c678d71028c fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=84ms status=200 bytes=612576
2015-07-31T17:49:20.872866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/slider-1-0c2992a412c083ec0a5e408dce1e9098.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=5d01f9c9-edb4-4afc-9870-112a74848479 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=64ms status=200 bytes=451537
2015-07-31T17:49:22.205778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/slider-2-21092d8448bef4abfad2e00c5bda3ab9.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=9d013a8f-501e-4a95-93ee-5a6e590fb0e4 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=667034
2015-07-31T17:49:22.563835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/page1-img2-7788f1952874c5b24b7fdffe50e165a4.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=e7974236-b160-47d9-ad4c-08a70cc28c4f fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=13602
2015-07-31T17:49:22.576304+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/page1-img3-3b94a8b99307e94e144d31980d6c251c.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=728c1300-22a5-49bd-9356-8bcec49d415b fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=11719
2015-07-31T17:49:22.606153+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/page1-img4-8834d46cb8455d0dc8406ec3242c4d08.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=b02abe6f-bd78-402d-a26d-5be985d962a4 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=23328
2015-07-31T17:49:22.573606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/page1-img1-90f46b9b07dec6d7bc8ec02fdd6019b0.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=a9110af3-61fc-4883-b87c-1d04f8845a85 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=14171
2015-07-31T17:49:22.683992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/prev.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=3332631b-67f3-4111-a213-4c35523e812f fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-07-31T17:49:22.586281+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/slider-3-91ee388062b58dc3b0a007f28c447ce2.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=e42c5dc7-1201-4e48-95f6-38bbda246461 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=365581
2015-07-31T17:49:22.680630+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/next.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=7ce98676-20eb-4a13-a44a-8d18791f1833 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-07-31T17:49:22.793308+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/icon-2.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=2dfbd56e-bb43-468f-bcc9-a3acfe53f4ab fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:49:22.704161+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/icon-3.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=5ff9ac6b-de6b-423f-a4f9-8a6099156f07 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669903+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669906+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/prev.png"):
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669908+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669909+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669915+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669918+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669919+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669920+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669921+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669922+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669923+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669926+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669927+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669928+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669929+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669930+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669931+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669932+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669934+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669935+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669936+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669937+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669938+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:49:22.669939+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:49:22.670744+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/images/next.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:49:22 +0000
2015-07-31T17:49:22.783335+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/icon-2.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:49:22 +0000
2015-07-31T17:49:22.800013+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/nav-bg.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:49:22 +0000
2015-07-31T17:49:22.885740+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/bc.jpg" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:49:22 +0000
2015-07-31T17:49:22.666502+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/images/prev.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:49:22 +0000
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672483+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672485+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/next.png"):
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672487+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672488+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672489+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672490+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672491+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672492+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672493+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672495+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672496+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672497+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672498+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672499+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672500+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672502+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672504+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672505+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672506+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672507+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672508+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672509+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672510+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672511+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:49:22.672512+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-31T17:49:22.688223+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/icon-3.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:49:22 +0000
2015-07-31T17:49:22.787975+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/icon-1.png" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:49:22 +0000
2015-07-31T17:49:22.804594+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/marker.gif" for 70.79.234.109 at 2015-07-31 17:49:22 +0000
2015-07-31T17:49:22.817567+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/marker.gif" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=772d3233-b015-4da8-a7ce-10700c80b55e fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:49:22.797875+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/icon-1.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=76fab0d7-2ce7-40dd-9777-e9877ad2d1f2 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:49:22.811446+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/nav-bg.png" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=3a85ecdf-34f9-4c5f-9da0-884f6b1bf356 fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=231
2015-07-31T17:49:22.895332+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/bc.jpg" host=presalevancouver.herokuapp.com request_id=fada1088-e90e-4194-8f95-212855b45d1a fwd="70.79.234.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=231
```

Comment: Actually that is digest, may be this helps you understand it and disable if needed https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/non-digested-asset-names-in-rails-4-your-options/